# Explaining directions to a Japanese tourist /useful phrases to know

Tags: grammar, word-choice, direction

Sorry if this might be too broad, I'm first time on this stackexchange.

Setup:
I'm walking around the town. I see a Japanese tourist looking at a city map and trying to find a landmark/restaurant/hotel on it and/or the landmark in this town. The problem is, it's the wrong map, the map of the town 100km to the North! Neither of us has smartphone. The tourist has tried to approach people for help but is being rudely ignored by the other people, so back to the (wrong) map he goes. I'd like to help him (being a good Samaritan that I am) so I approach.

The Japanese tourist speaks passable German, but doesn't speak or read English (or almost no English). I speak English very well, but do not know any German. Luckily for him, I like Japanese culture and know some basic Japanese (lets say, like a first or second grade primary school student) and I have some time to spare. The location looked for is not far away.

Questions:

1) How can I say the following (things in brackets are optional):

"(Don't worry.) I'll take you there/where you want to go. It is not far away.  No payment needed. (I have some time to spare.) Please follow me."

2)How do I go with actually giving directions? For example:

"Go straight/forward until you reach the semaphore/ the end of the street. You'll see red short building on your left side. Then turn right then go forward for 100 meters. Then turn left when you reach the tall white building. Then go forward for 200 meters. Then turn right and follow the path for 50 meters. The blue building on your right, with the number 22, is where you want to stop. Right across that building is 'location' you're looking for."

3) How would I add "then go" or "then do" after previous direction in grammatically correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) (心配いりません。）あなたが行きたいと思っている場所に連れて行って差し上げます。ここからそれほど遠くありませんので。料金はいただきません。（今、ヒマですので。）どうぞついてきてください。

2)　信号まで・この通りの最後までまっすぐ歩いて行って下さい。左手に赤いビルが見えて来ますので、右折して１００ｍほど進んで下さい。そこから左折して高い白いビルまで行って下さい。そこからさらに２００ｍ進んでから右に曲がり、小道を５０ｍほど進んでください。右手の青いビル、２２と書かれているビルをすぎれば目的地に着きます。

3) How would I add "then go" or "then do" after previous direction in grammatically correct way?
それから～～へ行って下さい。　それから～～をして下さい。